# My javascript quiz is not showing the results after submitting

Tags: javascript

I'm playing around with a javascript quiz but I'm having trouble showing the results. I would like the user to see the correct results when the user clicks on "Submit Answers" but nothing happens.

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Simple JavaScript Quiz </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

        <script  src="js/script.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <header>
                <h1> Simple JavaScript Quiz</h1>
                <p> Test your knowledge in <strong>JavaScript fundamentals</strong></p>
            </header>
            <section>
                <div id="results"> </div>

                <form name="quizForm" onsubmit="return submitAnswers()">

                <h3>1. In which elements do we put in JavaScript code?</h3>
                <img src="scam.png" alt="Italian Trulli">
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a">a. &lt;js&gt;<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b">b. &lt;script&gt;<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c">c. &lt;body&gt;<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" id="q1d">d. &lt;link&gt;<br>

                <h3>2. Which HTML attribute is used to reference an external JavaScript file?</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="a" id="q2a">a. src<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="b" id="q2b">b. rel<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="c" id="q2c">c. type<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="d" id="q2d">d.  href<br>

                <h3>3. How would you write "Hello" in an alert box?</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="q3" value="a" id="q3a">a. msg("Hello");<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q3" value="b" id="q3b">b. alertBox("Hello");<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q3" value="c" id="q3c">c. document.write("Hello");<br>
                <input type="radio" name="q3" value="d" id="q3d">d. alert("Hello");<br>

                <input type="submit" value="Submit Answers"> <br><br>

                </form>
            </section>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my javascript code:

```
function submitAnswers() {

    var total = 3;
    var score = 0;

    // get user input

    var q1 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q1"].value;
    var q2 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q2"].value;
    var q3 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q3"].value;

    // set correct answers

    var answers = ['b', 'a', 'd'];  

    // check answers (note i - 1 to account for array starting with [0])

    for (var i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
        if (eval("q" + i) == answers[i - 1]) {
            score++;
        }
    }

    // display results

    var results = document.getElementById("results");
    results.innerHTML ='<h3>You Scored <span> '+score+' </span> out of <span>'+total+'</span> </h3>';
    alert('You Scored '+score+' out of '+total); 
}
```

After I click "Submit Answers" nothing happens. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding onsubmit property directly in form element, add `submit` event listener on it and prevent the event from default behavior. Default behavior of submitig a form is refreshing whole page.

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  submitAnswers();
})
```